# how to get specific style value from css in selenium ide

Tags: selenium-ide

Got this:

```
<div class="photo" style="background-image: url("my-url.jpg");">   </div>
```

I have tryed this, but get an error:

```
javascript{window.document.getElementsByClassName('photo').getPropertyValue('background-image')}
```

I want to store "my-url.jpg" with selenium ide, so the value of background-image style, and my element has no id. anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Java version.
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your selector")).getAttribute("style");

Comment: I'm not sure it will help, because you use selenium driver syntax, and i'm using selenium ide only in my browser.

Comment: When you record your can save as a particular language, like Java. Save it, then find where you'd like to get the style. Add some logging msg there and output what you get for style to confirm you got it right.

Comment: but how do i run it? do i have to install eclipse and jUnit? i was looking for a "native" command in html...

Comment: Just play it back in the ide recorder tool

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to extract image Url:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>css=div.photo@style</td>
    <td>image_style</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeExpression</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['image_style'].split('(&quot;')[1]}</td>
    <td>image_url</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeExpression</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['image_url'].split('&quot;)')[0]}</td>
    <td>image_url</td>
</tr>
```